# Drop down list created in partial view not getting validated properly in view when rendered

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a MVC to create a project. I have a **view** in which user will enter all the data in **text boxes** and in **drop down lists**.

Those textboxes and drop down lists are **created in two separate partial views** and I'm rendering those partial views in one view.

My problem is **textbxes** are **getting validated properly** but **drop down lists are not getting validated even when I select values**.

> When I render only one partial view which displays textboxes my
>   control goes to respective Action Method. But when I render partial
>   view for drop down lists; it gives me validation errors even when I
>   select values in drop down lists

I will post my code.

Please remember that I'm posting only snippet of code as my partial view contains repeated code for textboxes and dropdown lists.

Sorry for the long snippets of code!!

Code for my partial view which displays textboxes

```
@model PITCRoster.tblUser
<script src="~/Content/CustomScripts/DatePickers.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>tblUser</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
// many other textboxes.
      </fieldset>
```

Code for my partial view which will display drop down lists

```
@model PITCRoster.ViewModel.LookUpViewModel
<script src="~/Content/CustomScripts/DatePickers.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLocation)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocation, Model.LocationList, "-Please select-")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLocation)
//many other dropdownlists
```

My View where I'm rendering these two partial views

```
@model PITCRoster.ViewModel.WrapperViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Resources";
}
<script src="~/Content/PopUp.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<h2>Resources</h2>
@{
    //Html.RenderPartial("_DisplayResources")
    Html.RenderPartial("_DisplayResources",Model.tblUser);
}


<div id="dialog">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddResource", "Resources", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            Html.RenderPartial("_CreateNewResource", new PITCRoster.tblUser());
           Html.RenderPartial("_LookUpDropDowns", Model.LookUpViewModel);
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        }
</div>
```

Here **WrapperViewModel** is a **ViewModel** class which contains **properties** having data which **required to render those partial views**.

Here is code for WrapperViewModel

```
public class WrapperViewModel
{
    //tblUser will be a property of class tblUser.
    public IEnumerable<tblUser> tblUser { get; set; }

    //It will contain property of class LookUpViewModel.
    public LookUpViewModel LookUpViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

All the **textboxes** are from the class **tblUser**
All the **dropdown** lists are from the class **LookUpViewModel**

Here is my **LookUpViewModel** class

```
 public class LookUpViewModel
    {
 [Display(Name = "Location")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a location")]
        public int SelectedLocation { get; set; }
  public SelectList LocationList { get; set; }
}
```

To understand this class please refer my question and solution for that question by **Stephen Muecke** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578598/viewmodel-getting-null-values-in-action-method)

Here's how I'm populating my data in **LocationList**

```
 RosterManagementEntities rosterManagementContext = new RosterManagementEntities();
            // populate your select lists
            var locations = from o in rosterManagementContext.tblCurrentLocations select o;
            model.LocationList = new SelectList(locations, "LocationId", "Location");
```

And here is my Action method for AddResource

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddResource(LookUpViewModel modelLookUp, tblUser tblUser)
        {
            Helpers.CopyLookUpViewModelTotblUser(modelLookUp, tblUser);
            return View(modelLookUp);
        }
```

**EDIT**

HTML generated for DropDownListFor() :

```
<select name="SelectedLocation" id="SelectedLocation" data-val-required="Please select a location" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Location must be a number." value="">
```

It also has `<option value = "">`

HTML generated for ValidationMessageFor() :

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="SelectedLocation" value=""/>
```

Thank you..

Comment: Can you inspect `ModelState` in the POST method and let us know what the errors are

Comment: @StephenMuecke When I click on create button after entering all the values, it still gets stuck on the page only asking to select value in drop down list.
So I guess I can't inspect ModelState

Comment: You also have a problem because you are duplicating scripts. Never put scripts in partial views - include them only on the main view

Comment: Moved all the scripts in view...
Still same problem

Comment: Also make sure you have no duplicates. Can you show the actual html generated for the `DropDownListFor()` and `ValidationMessageFor()` for one of the properties your referring to (including a few of the options you generate) - in particular, are the `value` attributes something that can be converted to `int`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please check my edit

Comment: Just a guess here.  You are posting your form back from the main view, thus you are sending the main view's model back in your post.  This model does not know about the values entered in your partial view, thus validation will fail

Comment: Something odd going on here - there should no be a `value` attribute in the `<select>` tag. And can you show some of the other options that are generated - the only one you have shown is the  (in full) `<option value="">Please select a location</option>` which if selected will of course generate an error

Comment: @akemp Is there anyway to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi @novice I've implemented most of the code you showed, and mine works fine, I'll post it as an answer so you can double check, I had to include a reference to `jquery to get it to work though\`

Comment: @StephenMuecke 
<option value=""> when I expand this I get the Text like
<option value=""> Text-A
<option value=""> Text-B
<option value=""> Text-C

Comment: Which means that all the values of your property `LocationId` of `tblCurrentLocations` is either `null` or an empty `string`. Check the data your populating.

Comment: @StephenMuecke No.. Data is not null or empty..

Comment: The values of `LocationId` must be `null` or an empty `string` because you get `<option value="">...</option>` If `LocationId` had a value of (say) 4, then you would get `<option value="4">....</option>`.

Comment: To prove this, use `var locations = new[] { new { LocationId = 1, Location = "Location 1" }, new { LocationId = 2, Location = "Location 2" }); model.LocationList = new SelectList(locations, "LocationId", "Location");`

Comment: Still it seems a little strange that something named `Location` outputs contains values `Text-A`, `Text-B` etc (or did you just show some dummy data? - if not are you sure you using the right `SelectList` data?)

Comment: I agree with @StephenMuecke can you add the definition of `tblCurrentLocations`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Tried your code...
Still doesn't work...
And Location contains data like Text-YCM1,Text-YCM2,Text-BJS1,Text-BJS2
I was using dummy data :)

Comment: Can my browser be an issue here?
I'm using IE9...

Comment: @novice does `tblCurrentLocations` contain a property `LocationId`

Comment: @3dd, It must, otherwise an exception would be thrown.

Comment: @novice, Then you have some other issue in your code that you have not shown us. What you have shown works perfectly well. Do you have any scripts that could be modifying the data. Also inspect the value of `model.LocationList` in in VS to confirm that the `Value` property of each `SelectListItem` is being set.

Comment: Yea you might be right... my script might be changing my code somewhere...
I'll take a look

Answer (score 1):

I've duplicated your code and mine works fine, this is what I did

`LookUpViewModel.cs`

```
public class LookUpViewModel {
    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a location")]
    public int SelectedLocation { get; set; }

    public SelectList LocationList { get; set; }
}
```

`tblCurrentLocations.cs`

```
public class tblCurrentLocations {
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string Location {get;set;}
}
```

`tblUser.cs`

```
public class tblUser {
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name required")]
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

I used the `Index` method on my `HomeControler` to render the initial `View`

```
public ActionResult Index() {
        var locations = new List<tblCurrentLocations>();
        locations.Add(new tblCurrentLocations {LocationId = 1, Location = "A"});
        locations.Add(new tblCurrentLocations {LocationId = 2, Location = "B"});

        var model = new WrapperViewModel();
        model.LookUpViewModel = new LookUpViewModel() {
            LocationList = new SelectList(locations, "LocationId", "Location")
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

`_CreateNewResource.cshtml`

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.tblUser

<fieldset>
<legend>tblUser</legend>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>
// many other textboxes.
```

`_LookUpDropDowns.cshtml`

```
model WebApplication1.Models.LookUpViewModel

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLocation)

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocation, Model.LocationList, "-Please select-")

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLocation)
```

And finally the view that render all the `Partials`

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.WrapperViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Resources";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<h2>Resources</h2>

<div id="dialog">
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddResource", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    Html.RenderPartial("_CreateNewResource", new WebApplication1.Models.tblUser());
    Html.RenderPartial("_LookUpDropDowns", Model.LookUpViewModel);
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

This worked fine for me regarding `validation` and posting the selected results, you mentioned that there are more to the view than what you posted, perhaps something else on the views are causing trouble.  Also note I has to add `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>` to get validation to work, which you have ommited

Comment: See my last comment to the question to see what the real issue is :)

Comment: Check that you populate the `SelectList` with correct values